# What is dataset of BaseAdapter

Tags: android

When we use ArrayAdapter we pass something like a list to the super class. But base adapter constructor doesn't have any parameters. How does this class find the data set? I have seen in some examples they just define an array and override the functions without specifying the list as the Dataset. So how does the class understand this is the dataset? What if we define more than one list in the derived class?

Edit:
I think I should clarify my question. When we use ArrayAdapter the dataset is specified and the program knows what to iterate and calls getView for each of them. But in BaseAdapter we only define a list and override 4 functions and it works! My question is why does it work?! we didn't specify the dataset we just specify the getView body and it returns a view. I don't understand how the program finds the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after more considerations on the codes I think this is how base adapter works:

It loops the getView() function with 'position' parameter to be from 0 to what is returned by getCount().
we must override getCount() and send the correct index of the last item of dataSet. Each time getView() is called we can work with the views and any list we want according to the current position.
And I think the main difference between ArrayAdapter and BaseAdapter is that ArrayAdapter finds the last index of the list when we pass it to the super class but in base Adapter we should define the last index. Implementation of getView() is the same and we can use any list we want in getView. The trick was only about position parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation explains it well :

> Common base class of common implementation for an Adapter

Means you have to do the implementation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Comment: I have already read it. The only thing I implement is getView(). And getview is called for every item of the list. My question is this list. That we didn't specify it as the dataSet so how does the AdapterView consider it as dataset then calls getView for it?

Comment: You have to define it, as you extend the class, just as some variables to this class, and change the onCreate method, create your own setter for the data, implement the rest.

Comment: 1. The Object list is defined in the derived class.
2. getView and a few other functions are implemented.
3. Done
the getView is called for all of the list items... Where did we specify what the dataset is? can you show me an example that specified the dataset for the AdapterView or BaseClass?

Comment: I think this page sums everything up :
http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.fr/
You have to define the  getItemViewType(int position) and  getViewTypeCount(), these will be called by the adapter to create the new view (sort of loop on all positions from 0 to getViewTypeCount if i'm right)

Answer (score 0):

> How does this class find the data set?

It doesn't. Your subclass of `BaseAdapter` manages the data set.

> What if we define more than one list in the derived class?

So long as you implement the `abstract` `Adapter` methods properly (`getCount()`, `getView()`, `getItem()`, `getItemId()`, ...), how you manage your own data is up to you.

Comment: In ArrayAdapter for each of the items of the list getView is called. So is for BaseAdapter. But how? We don't pass the list to super class in Baseadapter. In examples I saw there was just a getView function and a list. There was nothing like a loop to call getView for each of them. What calls getView and for what DataSet?

Comment: @user2808671: "What calls getView" -- the `AdapterView` that is using the `Adapter`, such as the `ListView`. "for what DataSet?" -- whatever you want. `ArrayAdapter` adapts arrays. `CursorAdapter` adapts `Cursors`. I once wrote a `JSONAdapter` that adapted a `JSONArray`. And so on. It is up to the developer of the subclass of `BaseAdapter` to determine what the data set is and how to meet the `Adapter` contract.

Comment: Well, only defining a list with some variables and returning a textView in getView() body does the job! In getView() I only write textView.setText(list[position]). But what does the AdapterView call the getView for? You say we ourselves determine? I don't find a line of code to determine this. But the program works. There is only a list and a getView function and the adapterView calls getView for all the list. I ask how adapter view knows to call getView for what list?

Comment: @user2808671: "But what does the AdapterView call the getView for?" -- to get the views to put on the screen. `ListView`, for example, uses `getView()` to retrieve the list rows.

Comment: From that question I meant 'For What list' does the adapter view calls the getView function? I don't Understand this I don't find any piece of code in any example that specified the dataset in baseclass. I only see that AdapterView calls getView for the list which is used in getView(). Whatever list is used in getView is iterated and considered as DataSet.

Comment: @user2808671: "Whatever list is used in getView is iterated and considered as DataSet" -- exactly. If you search the Web for `"extends baseadapter"`, you will find many examples of subclasses of `BaseAdapter`. You may wish to examine some of those to see how others have implemented adapters for custom data sets.